# Correlation for two variables in a group by condition in R

Tags: r

Below is how my data looks like.

```
Name, Salary, Age
New York, 45000,34
New York, 47000, 35
New York , 35000, 28
New York, 23000, 27
Mexico , 56000, 34
Mexico , 67000, 35
Mexico , 63300, 45
Mexico, 31000, 31
```

I would like to have correlation between Salary and Age, for every group separately. I don't want to mix the data between groups. I tried the for loop approach in R, but no luck!

One more question, do i need to standardize my data before correlation. I assume that is not required? I did it for PCA earlier, hence just trying to reclarify it for a basic correlation output.

I am looking for output like below:

```
City, Correlation
Mexico, 0.756
New York, 0.465
```

Any leads would be highly appreciated!

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 0):

An option using `dplyr` and `cor`.

**Updated:**  Based on feedback from @Frank

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(Name) %>%
  summarise(Correlation = cor(Age, Salary))
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
# Name     Correlation
# <chr>          <dbl>
# 1 Mexico         0.614
# 2 New York       0.935

df <- read.table(text = 
"Name, Salary, Age
'New York', 45000,34
'New York', 47000, 35
'New York', 35000, 28
'New York', 23000, 27
Mexico, 56000, 34
Mexico, 67000, 35
Mexico, 63300, 45
Mexico, 31000, 31",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = ",")
```

Comment: Why not `summarise(cor = cor(Age, Salary))`?

Comment: @Frank Agree. You are absolutely correct.  Perhaps OP is looking for `cor`.